# How to make nftables duplicate multiple interfaces to one interface

Tags: routing, nftables, bro

My home router has 2 internal interfaces on different subnets, and one external interface plugged into the comcast modem. I'd like to duplicate every packet that *enters* each interface out to a single virtual interface, at which I can direct Zeek. I *think* this should help me get full introspection of network traffic without duplicate logs like I'd get if I had Zeek monitor each interface separately.

While this works to duplicate traffic to "dummy0":

```
nft add table netdev filter
nft add chain netdev filter ingress { \
type filter hook ingress device eth0 priority 0\; }
nft add rule netdev filter ingress dup to dummy0
```

I cannot seem to extend it to also hook to additional ethernet devices. I find the nftables documentation to be extremely sparse on this sort of thing, so recommendations are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With older nftables / kernel: one netdev basechain is registered to exactly one network device. If you need to duplicate the traffic of multiple interfaces, just create again a basechain with this same rule, registered to the other interface:

```
nft add table netdev filter
nft add chain netdev filter ingress0 '{ type filter hook ingress device eth0 priority 0; }'
nft add chain netdev filter ingress1 '{ type filter hook ingress device eth1 priority 0; }'
nft add rule netdev filter ingress0 dup to dummy0
nft add rule netdev filter ingress1 dup to dummy0
```

With nftables [>= 0.9.3](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/?h=v0.9.3&id=3fdc7541fba079f9626bcb1605368a7da3a8d81a) and kernel [>= 5.5](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=v5.5&id=d54725cd11a57c30f650260cfb0a92c268bdc3e0): the same netdev basechain can register to multiple devices, avoiding the duplication:

```
nft add table netdev filter
nft add chain netdev filter ingress '{ type filter hook ingress devices = { eth0, eth1 } priority 0; }'
nft add rule netdev filter ingress dup to dummy0
```